# Javascript live search

Tags: jquery

On one of my sites, I have a list of courses with a search box that eliminates/removes list objects if they are not relevant to what the user has typed in.  Problem is if the course name does not match in the same order, my script returns 0 results.

Example:  One of the list items is called "Mobile Slewing Crane Up to 60t" but if someone types in mobile crane, it does not match.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?  Below is a copy of the JS and the HTML list that it runs against.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Timothy

```
 <input type="text" id="CourseS" name="CourseS" value="" placeholder="Find a course" class="form-control">
<ul class="list_courses col-md-12">
    <li class="list_courses_list">
        <h5>Crane Training</h5>
        <ul class="qualifications-links">
           <li>Mobile Slewing crane A</li>
           <li>Mobile Slewing crane B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list_courses_list">
        <h5>Short Courses</h5>
        <ul class="qualifications-links">
            <li>Short Course A</li>
            <li>Short Course B</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#CourseS").on("keyup", function() {
        jQuery("p.NoResultsFound").remove();
        var a = jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase();
        jQuery(".list_courses li").each(function() {
            var d = jQuery(this);
            if (d.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(a) < 0) {
                d.hide()
            } else {
                d.show()
            }
        });
        var c = jQuery(".list_courses li:visible").length.toString();
        var b = "<p class='NoResultsFound'>No courses found</p>";
        if (c == 0) {
            jQuery("ul.list_courses").prepend(b)
        } else {
            jQuery("p.NoResultsFound").remove()
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: jquery [quicksearch](http://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) may help you.